# Canadian specific terminology

Tags: translation

I am working on a translation of a Canadian politics text, and the document talks about Aboriginal youth offenders and non-Aboriginal youth offenders.

Typically when we speak of Aboriginal people in Canada I translate it as "Ureinwohner." Does anybody have suggestions how to translate the above phrase concerning offenders

> "Jugendliche Straftäter, die Ureinwohner sind."

but without using the next relative clause.

Comment: "Jugendliche Straftäter, die Ureinwohner sind."

Comment: Ohne jeglichen Migrationshintergrund. ;-)

Comment: Probably, *kanadische Indianer* would work, too, but I can see that being considered a discriminating term by the aboriginal people if they prefer the latter.

Comment: We use the English term First Nations for the traditional German "Indianer" but that's different than Aboriginal/Ureinwohner.

Comment: @Kanadier So *aboriginal* covers a larger group than *First Nations*?

Comment: Yes in Canada the term Aboriginal refers to First Nations, Inuit and Métis peoples. Indigenous is interchangeable but is not the preferred Canadian term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that came to mind was *[eingeboren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eingeboren_angestammt_angeboren)*.

However, I found the following note in the Duden entry for *[Eingeborener](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eingeborener)*:

> Besonderer Hinweis
>   Die Bezeichnung Eingeborener wird zunehmend als diskriminierend empfunden. Neutralere Ausweichformen für die Verwendung im Plural sind Urbevölkerung bzw. einheimische Bevölkerung, Ureinwohnerinnen und Ureinwohner oder die fachsprachliche Bezeichnung Autochthone.

It says that the word is increasingly understood in a pejorative sense. But it also brings up two other words: *[einheimisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einheimisch)* and *[autochthon](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/autochthon)*.
However, the former one does not necessarily convey the idea of aboriginal, and the latter one is probably not widely understood. I, at least, didn't know that word.
Finally, there's also *[indigen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/indigen)* which I guess is my personal favorite term here.

So, here are the four suggestions in order of my personal priority.

> indigene jugendliche Straftäter
>   einheimische jugendliche Straftäter
>   autochthone jugendliche Straftäter
>   eingeborene jugendliche Straftäter

Comment: I really like the usage of "indigene" and might go with that! Does the (non)word "ureinwohnerisch" make any sense in German? The text is for kids who have been using the word Ureinwohner and it would be nice if I could keep the term consistent.

Comment: @Kanadier It's probably readily comprehensible, but not really a word – as you figured. I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

May be

> aboriginale jugendliche Straftäter

would help. If not, set *Ureinwohner* as the principal noun, and adjectivize *Sträftäter*:

> straffällige jugendliche Ureinwohner

---

To the OP's question to this answer, you can see how in German the term *aboriginal* dominated and from the early 90s on, *indigen* dominates.

(Of course, this doesn't mean they mean the same thing)

[image]

Comment: *Straftätig* gibt’s nicht. Eher *straffällige*, oder *straffällig gewordene*.

Comment: Two questions about this answer: I am not a native speaker, but I don't think "aboriginal" is a standard German term, is it? Secondly, if you move Ureinwohner to the noun, is there more of a negative weight on the word Aboriginal?

Comment: @Kanadier So. Now I hope you can see how standard *was*. Apparently *indigen* seems better.

Comment: *Aboriginal* sounds extremely weird. Using *indigen* as a more politically correct way to say *Indian* or w/e is a relatively new phenomenon, so it probably still needs to gain ground.

Answer (score 2):

Statt *Ureinwohner*, das besser im Kontext aktiver Kolonisation verwendet wird, also für Nordamerika je nach Region von 1500 bis 1900, kann man alternativ bilden:

> *urkanadische* jugendliche Straftäter
>   *uramerikanische* jugendliche Straftäter

*Urkanadier / Uramerikaner* sind vermutlich **Neologismen**, aber einigermaßen aus sich heraus verständlich und diskriminierungsarm, denn *ur-* besagt, dass sie keinerlei ausländische Wurzeln haben. Die Vorsilbe findet sich zwar in *Urgroßeltern* u.ä., wird aber ansonsten eher selten für Personenbezeichnungen verwendet. In *urdeutsche Tugenden* (Fleiß, Pünktlichkeit, Sorgfalt und Bla) hat es bspw. die gewünschte Bedeutung,

> *altkanadische* jugendliche Straftäter
>   *altamerikanische* jugendliche Straftäter

*Alt~* ginge evtl. auch, aber gerade die Antonyme mit *Neu~* lassen intuitiv eher ‚selbst eingewandert‘ (vs. ‚hier geboren‘) statt *mit familiären Migrationshintergrund* anklingen. In *altdeutsche Tugenden* (Gehorsam etc.) hat es eher die Bedeutung ‚veraltet‘. Das nur (noch) in bestimmten Kreisen gebräuchliche *Alteltern* bezeichnet eine Generation vor den Urgroßeltern.

> jugendliche Straftäter *mit präkolumbischen Wurzeln*

*präkolumbisch* ist ein bisschen umständlich und schlechter verständlich.

PS: *straffällig gewordene Jugendliche* ist zumindest im Plural geschlechtsneutral, *jugendliche Straftäter* hingegen nicht und *jugendliche ?Straffälliggewordene* klänge arg gestelzt.